# Operation to downscale deployment to 0 after 50 restarts

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-pod

Operation to downscale deployments when there are too many restarts. So for example when a deployment restarts 10 times or 50 times it will automatically downscale to zero

Is this some kind of possible with basic setup or do I need to write something?

Comment: In Kubernetes?  The Pod will automatically go into CrashLoopBackOff state, and if this is in the process of updating a Deployment then it won't go forward creating new Pods, but the cluster won't automatically kill off healthy Pods because some are unhealthy.

Comment: CrashLoopBackoff will only kick in if the pod won't start. I think a controller is required for this then?

Comment: @Danny : Have you tried this issue with the controller ? Is your issue resolved? If yes, please post your answer for a Greater visibility to the Community.